# Clickable div modification...need the script to find a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".post-entry").click(function() {
  window.location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to modify this script to find a href link that has a specific class? The reason is that some of these divs have multiple links within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
$('.post-entry').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('a.example-class').attr('href')
    return false;
})
```

If you want a hand cursor, you'll need a bit of CSS too:

```
.post-entry {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: How would I add the hand cursor so it looks like a link?

Comment: Did the above edit answer your question?

Comment: It did indeed. Thank you!

Comment: I marked it as the accepted answer :) Is it possible with this type of link to have the url show in the browser status bar link a standard link?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question -- setting `window.location` should automatically update the URL bar.

Comment: It's not really a status bar...but in Chrome and Edge, when you hover over a hyperlink, a gray "caption" appears at the bottom left of the browser window that shows the full url. That doesn't appear when hovering your cursor within the clickable div...even though the link works.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be adding a `title="tooltip text"` attribute, which allows you to show text next to your cursor. That might get a little annoying, though; your call.

Comment: It's working fine now, thanks!